# Trigger CSS animations by hovering over a seperate element

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a small animation on an image (the image grows slightly) when a link is hovered over using only CSS3 animations.

The relevant snippets from my code

HTML:

```
<img id="enterimg" src="img.png" alt="" />
<a id="enterbutton" href="home.php">Enter</a>
```

CSS:

```
#enterimg {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out;
  transition: width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out;
}

a:hover ~ #enterimg{width:400px;height:400px;}
```

I'm sure the transitions themselves are correct, but none of the different "calls" (the last line of CSS) I've tried have worked.

(This is similar to a number of other questions, but I've looked through them and as far as I can tell none of them answer my question)

Comment: Checkout this plugin.. it uses css3 and is easy to use with jquery: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: There is no prev sibling selector currently. What you can do is that you can modify your markup to put anchor before image or wrap them both in a div and trigger animation when div is triggered.

Comment: If you wrap the item you want to move in the hovered item, you can do this. CSS can't "call" horizontally as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think about the markup order, that's fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lokesh Suthar.

The order of the sibling selector required I placed the link first in the markup. Since the selection was written:

```
a:hover ~ #enterimg{width:400px;height:400px;}
```

The markup needed to be in that order

```
<a id="enterbutton" href="home.php">Enter</a>
<img id="enterimg" src="img.png" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the content in the trigger, then position the content absolutely, you can achieve something similar to triggering a sibbling with CSS. At least it'll look and act that way.

HTML

```
<a href="">Click Me
    <img id="enterimg" src="http://www.druglessdrs.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/google-logo-small.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

CSS

```
a img {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:0;
    border:solid 1px black;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out;
}

a:hover img {
    left:50px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/58NUe/1/)